# Вывод строки и смежные строки +-2

Tags: php, mysql

Есть mysql таблица из 200000 строк. Нужно вывести основную строку и смежные с ней строки +-2 строки.

Логика такая. Человек вводит в инпут поле ник и должен увидеть, где он находится в топе. Например: ввел ник - tornado и получил ответ.

```
1030 --/-/
1031 --/-/
1032 tornado
1033 --/-/
1034 --/-/
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать такой запрос в базу данных?

Comment: Версия MySQL какая?

Comment: Версия mysql-5.7.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  (  
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM sourcetable t1
    JOIN sourcetable t2 ON t2.nick = 'tornado' AND t1.rank >= t2.rank 
    ORDER BY rank LIMIT 3
  )
UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM sourcetable t1
    JOIN sourcetable t2 ON t2.nick = 'tornado' AND t1.rank < t2.rank 
    ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 2
  )
ORDER BY rank
```

Comment: Спасибо, отпишусь.

Comment: Все работает, огромное спасибо

Comment: @Ренат Тогда пометьте решение как принятое, что ли...

Comment: Верно, сделано!

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() как правильно к такому запросу прописать?

Comment: @Ренат А назачем оно в этом запросе? равно как и для указанной версии сервера...

Comment: В этой версии эта функция не поддерживается, нам нужно вывести номер строки, это и будет как раз считаться местом в рейтинге

Comment: Нумерация - стандартная задача. На пятерке делается с использованием переменных.

Comment: Есть одна проблема, тот код, что я ниже скинул работает хорошо, когда значения разные, но в случае, когда, например, 500 совпадений, то в этом случае строки прыгают рандомно.

Comment: @Ренат. Так это нормально. Нужна определённость - нужно расширить выражение сортировки. Вообще-то по нему записи должны быть уникальны...

Answer (score 0):

```
У меня получилось реализовать таким путем, каждый ник получил номер строки. Если есть лучше решение, я конечно вас внимательно выслушаю.

(
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT *, @i:=@i+1 AS `RowNumber`
FROM sourcetable, (SELECT @i:=0) AS `RowNumberTable` ORDER BY '.$category_x.' DESC) t1
JOIN sourcetable t2 ON t2.nickname = "'.$nick.'" AND t1.'.$category_x.' >= t2.'.$category_x.' 
ORDER BY '.$category_x.' LIMIT 3
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT *, @n:=@n+1 AS `RowNumber`
FROM sourcetable, (SELECT @n:=0) AS `RowNumberTable` ORDER BY '.$category_x.' DESC) t1
JOIN sourcetable t2 ON t2.nickname = "'.$nick.'" AND t1.'.$category_x.' < t2.'.$category_x.' 
ORDER BY '.$category_x.' DESC LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY '.$category_x.' DESC
';
```

Comment: Если этот ORDER BY не обеспечивает уникальности, то записи по-прежнему могут "прыгать".

Comment: Пробовал разные сортировки, не нашел, к сожалению, пока идею, как сделать все правильно. Ниже два варианта, скинул для наглядности

Answer (score 0):

В случае сортировки по **боям**, все слетает, т.к. значения одинаковые. Не нашел ту самую сортировку, при которой от искомого ника, вверх и вниз, таблица получит упорядоченные номера, без прыжков.

```
Место - 63314 Ник - Diesel Black 73,  Боев - 110,  Побед - 42.34, Урон - 805.08
Место - 63290 Ник - AmazedRiver4,     Боев - 110,  Побед - 48.65, Урон - 836.00
Место - 63306 Ник - CZARNY-KOT-1986,  Боев - 110,  Побед - 60.36, Урон - 2671.19
Место - 63298 Ник - Bonker Conkers,   Боев - 110,  Побед - 53.15, Урон - 1541.38
Место - 63449 Ник - Boat Bomber 95,   Боев - 110,  Побед - 40.91, Урон - 1161.75
Место - 63593 Ник - xXCo-ckZil-laXx,  Боев - 111,  Побед - 55.45, Урон - 2086.64
Место - 63465 Ник - DirePegasus4677,  Боев - 111,  Побед - 30.91, Урон - 727.38
Место - 63441 Ник - baratto86,        Боев - 111,  Побед - 45.45, Урон - 1316.46
Место - 63585 Ник - wws_1980,         Боев - 111,  Побед - 48.18, Урон - 1519.14
Место - 63457 Ник - chronicseed666,   Боев - 111,  Побед - 40.00, Урон - 817.19
Место - 63433 Ник - aliakberov1968,   Боев - 111,  Побед - 50.00, Урон - 958.22
```

В случае сортировки по **урону**, все хорошо.

```
Место - 9712  Ник - SubtleErmine7,    Боев - 227,  Побед - 49.78, Урон - 2172.58
Место - 9713  Ник - busja1991,        Боев - 102,  Побед - 52.94, Урон - 2172.57
Место - 9714  Ник - kiiro2-jp-,       Боев - 43,   Побед - 67.44, Урон - 2172.53
Место - 9715  Ник - WoT_Console,      Боев - 111,  Побед - 56.76, Урон - 2172.50
Место - 9716  Ник - Actual Mods,      Боев - 61,   Побед - 45.90, Урон - 2172.38
Место - 9717  Ник - hA Snipes,        Боев - 197,  Побед - 55.84, Урон - 2172.34
Место - 9718  Ник - SANRAMO,          Боев - 82,   Побед - 50.00, Урон - 2172.27
Место - 9719  Ник - Solenya86,        Боев - 249,  Побед - 51.81, Урон - 2172.23
Место - 9720  Ник - Dude4Life73,      Боев - 119,  Побед - 59.66, Урон - 2172.20
Место - 9721  Ник - SweepingDuck80,   Боев - 336,  Побед - 55.65, Урон - 2172.19
Место - 9722  Ник - I WOMBO00,        Боев - 43,   Побед - 62.79, Урон - 2172.12
```